# "Cannot execute binary file" when running compiled c++ programs with Eclipse on Ubuntu for Windows platform

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, cross-platform, mingw32

I would like to move from Visual Studio on Windows platform to Eclipse on Ubuntu for c++ development, since I develop almost all my programs on Java, with Eclipse, and I just use a Windows virtual machine in order to develop C++ programs for Win OS. So if I would be happy being able to not use Windows VM at all. However, I've managed to configure MinGW and Eclipse successfully enough to compile programs, but not to execute them.

Steps I've gone through so far:

I've installed mingw32 package and dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mingw32
```

I've installed Eclipse Mars for C/C++ development (manually, to keep this installation isolated from other Eclipses I have) and created a new project in this way:

```
- New C++ project.
- [...]
- Cross-prefix: i586-mingw32msvc-
- Cross path: /usr/bin/
```

With this configuration I'm able to correctly build a .exe which I can successfully execute on Windows, but when trying to debug it or execute it under Eclipse I get this error: "cannot execute binary file".

Googleing I've seen some posts suggesting to use wine in order to execute the .exe, but I thought mingw32 would be able to execute it. Am I wrong and this is not possible or just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mingw32 is a windows compiler, and will compile source to a Windows executable file. Additionally, the *compiler* cannot *execute* files (as worded in the question), it just compiles the source code to an executable form, in this case the windows executable (*.exe). So yes, in order to run the .exe in Ubuntu you would need something like Wine which emulates a Windows environment

Answer (score 1):

mingw is a set of GNU tools for building native Windows executables.
It does not execute anything.
If you really want to cross-compile for Windows, you need Windows or an emulator for the execution.

To build for Ubuntu you can just use the native compilers.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```